# Ahmadiya considered to be Non-Muslims , Falsifying the Islam

Tags: non-muslim, ahmadiyyah

Asalamoalikum ! I want to know more about Why Ahmadiya are considered Non-Muslims? Can someone please provide me with extensive detail? JazakAllah:)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as-written, it is highly problematic and likely to attract problematic answers. We as a site are not here to define anyone as disbelievers, or who is or is not a Muslim, and blanket statements defining Ahmadiya as "Non-Muslims, falsifying the Islam" as if it's universally accepted are not respectful of their beliefs, which is required behaviour on this site. See also our [Code of Conduct](https://islam.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: If you feel this question is valuable and should be reopened, please start a discussion in [meta] on how this question can best conform to the rules and regulations of the site, and how it can be written in a way that treats all parties involved with respect and without unnecessary bias.

Comment: It is a genuine question. We should provide proper answer instead of running away.

Answer (score 2):

Because they believe in and follow Mirza Ghulam Ahmad who claimed to be a prophet and claimed to have received revelations. This is contrary to core Islamic belief of the end of prophethood with Muhammad ﷺ. They also deviate in other beliefs which are considered necessities of religion, e.g. they believe that Jihad has been abrogated.

Reference: http://www.iifa-aifi.org/1576.html